# it's better/faster making a view and add subviews programatically than using a storyboard

Tags: ios

Is it more efficient to add views and subviews programmatically than using a  storyboard to add them ?

What is be the best practice ? Does the best practice depend on the situation ?  If so, when is it preferable to use the one method over the other ?

Answer (score 2):

Storyboard vs Code comes up an awful lot. And I think looking at it as which is better often starts flame wars. So instead I'll list out pros and cons for each, then you can hopefully make an informed decision.

*This is by no means an exhaustive list. I'd love to see edits or comments adding additional bullet points.*

**Storyboard Pros**

- Storyboards are great for getting a concept working quickly.
- They're great for seeing your actual app and previewing it on multiple devices.
- They make it really easy to customize appearances and explore whats possible.
- They're fantastic for beginners as they remove one barrier and let you focus on code for your app rather than some boiler plate UI.

**Storyboard Cons**

- Storyboards and Xibs are not great for merging. Its possible to read the XML and make decisions about merge conflicts, but its certainly not enjoyable.
- Overtime as you customize your app and build the custom parts that make it special, Storyboards can't keep up. This means that the benefit of seeing and previewing your app as you see it on device slowly loses its value as more and more of your app is done in code out of necessity.
- Storyboards don't have a huge performance hit for actual users, but they definitely slow Xcode down on even the fastest machines.
- You can't customize everything in Interface Builder that you can in code, so its inevitable you'll have some code and some Storyboard customization. Later when you want to change something, you'll have to check at least two places for the right place to change it.
- If you're using the same fonts and colors throughout the app, its easy to change in code in one place. In Storyboard you'll need to change it for every single label or view you've set up. You can easily set fonts and colors in code while using Storyboard for the rest of your layout, but over time you'll find your storyboards represent less and less of your actual app.
- While its possible to have pixel perfect designs in Storyboard, drag and drop isn't as precise as entering specific numbers. Storyboard does support entering those numbers, but you need to navigate to multiple places and if you drag it later the numbers are all reset.
- Reusing views typically involves copy and pasting them. These causes issues later when you need to make changes.
- Showing and hiding views at certain times is doable, but again leaves your storyboard in an unrealistic state compared to your actual app.

**Programmatic Pros**

- All your code is in one place making it easier to debug or change later.
- Subclasses and custom properties are no different from first class views and properties. Your customizations will be easy to manage.
- Views that are reused throughout the app only need to be created once.
- Merge conflicts are often easy to understand and make decisions.
- Dependency Injection is one of the safest ways to instantiate UIViewControllers and ensure necessary information is passed in, its not possible with Storyboards leading to less straight forward and more bug prone code.

**Programmatic Cons**

- The additional complexity can be a stumbling block for beginners.
- Writing a few lines of code can take longer than clicking a few checkboxes.
- When working with layouts, you'll need to visualize it in your head or run your app to see what your layout looks like as you make changes. This can be difficult or slower for some.
- Storyboard exposes checkboxes and buttons for many customizable properties like background color, font, etc. This makes it easy to see at a glance what you can customize. (Though as mentioned above its not everything) In Code, you'll need to look at documentation or headers to understand what you can customize.

Comment: Most of the storyboard cons are valid only if you don't use storyboards right. Storyboards slow down xcode only if you are making huge storyboards which is definitely not correct. You actually can customize everything in storyboard and also you can set custom classes, designables etc. Reusing views by copying them is not the best what you can do. Merging is actually the only big problem that can be reduced a lot when you are using small storyboards because the probability of two people modyfing the same xib/storyboard is minimized.

Comment: For complicated layouts it takes an enormous time to set constraints correctly in code, considering you have no validation, you cannot see missing constraints and you cannot switch easily to a different size class. It's important to understand code but must of the layout work should be in xibs/storyboards.

Comment: Large storyboards aren't the only way to slow down Xcode. Designable's require compiling which drastically affect Storyboard performance for even medium sized apps. Setting custom classes ensures you get the proper object but your storyboard doesn't match the class at all. Reusing views there are better ways but all require code to my knowledge.

Comment: Setting constraints in code is typically faster for me because you need less and they can be more precise. But that may just be my experience level playing in (lots of experience in code, less in storyboard). However I think its an objective fact that changing those constraints after the fact is always faster and safer in code. So perhaps it should be looked at as an investment in the future to use code. Think of Storyboards as a valuable shortcut for their pros.

Comment: Compiling can be done faster, e.g. by moving your designables to a separate target. I have zero performance problems with my storyboards and I work on a laptop.
There is absolutely nothing safer about constraints in code considering Interface Builder always validates your constraints. There is nothing faster about it. Changing one number in code and changing one number in IB takes the same time. Maybe finding the correct constraint in IB will take less time than finding the correct constraint in code. Constaints in code are not more precise than constraints in IB, they have the same options.

Comment: For constraints built in code, I have a few utilities that let me do this very easily, readable and with very little code. Say you have three buttons and you want to insert another one between #2 and #3. Very simple with code. A pain in a storyboard.

Comment: Stack views help a lot on the layout front. Both in Storyboard and in Code. Sorta negating the moving view stuff around. But visual format language is really nice for visually laying out a view. And its diffable in merges making conflicts a breeze.